# Inverse factorial summation proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation

Prove that $\sum_{d=1}^{J}{d \over {(J+d)!(J-d)!}} = {1 \over {2\Gamma(J)\Gamma(J+1)}}$ where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function. I came across this at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html equation(22) that assumes it. I tried to transform this into a telescoping sum but that did not work out. Any hints?

Comment: why do you use tau to indicate the gamma function? use \Gamma instead : $\Gamma$

Comment: @Ant Thank you for the suggestion! Edited the question.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) ?

Comment: @Lucian I wasn't but now I am! But I still don't see how I can apply that here.

Comment: @karmanaut: Never mind. Just multiply and divide by $(2J)!$, and then rewrite entire identity as $$\sum_{k=0}^n{2n\choose n+k}k~=~\frac n2~{2n\choose n},$$ for which a simple combinatorial proof can be offered.

Comment: Elegant! If you can write this as an answer, I can accept and close this. Thanks!

Comment: @karmanaut: Better yet, why don't you write up the answer yourself ? This way, you'll learn more. $($The site allows and even encourages us to answer our own questions, and accept our own answers$)$.

Comment: @Lucian I just posted an answer. If you have a couple of minutes to spare, do glance over to see if it looks right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We rewrite $\sum_{d=1}^{J}{d \over {(J+d)!(J-d)!}}$ as $\sum_{d=1}^{J}{{d.(2J)!} \over {(2J)!(J+d)!(J-d)!}} = \sum_{d=1}^{J}{{d} \over {(2J)!}}{2n \choose n+d} = \sum_{d=1}^{J}{{d} \over {(2J)!}}{2n \choose n-d} $. We now give a combinatorial proof of $\sum_{d=1}^{J}{d}{2n \choose n-d} = {n \over 2}{2n \choose n}$.

Consider $n$ boys and $n$ girls. We need to form a team of $n$ children in total with a girl as captain. We can do this by choosing $n-d$ children and $d$ girls $= {2n \choose n-d}$. We can assign the captain in $d$ ways. This can also be done by choosing $1$ girl as captain in $n$ ways and let her choose remaining $n-1$ teammates from $2n-1$ members. This gives the count as $n{{2n-1} \choose {n-1}} = {n \over 2}{2n \choose n}$.

Therefore, $\sum_{d=1}^{J}{d \over {(J+d)!(J-d)!}} = {1 \over (2J)!}{J \over 2}{(2J)! \over {J!J!}} = {1 \over {2\Gamma(J)\Gamma(J+1)}}$

Comment: Sounds about right...

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the part where you said the number of ways of "choosing $n−d$ children and $d$ girls" is ${2n \choose n−d}$ and there are $d$ ways to assign the captain? Wouldn't the $n-d$ children also possibly include some girls?